# Depth of field clarification

Tags: depth-of-field

What is the range of depth of ﬁeld when using the hyperfocal distance?

I am looking to get clarification on this topic.

Comment: wow, have you looked through the site for answers to all your questions.  Most of them have been well covered. It would be helpful if you could read what is already on the site on these topics, for example [What is “Hyperfocal Distance”?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-is-hyperfocal-distance) and then ask specific questions if there is something you still don't understand.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) - "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. 
Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much"

Answer (score 3):

Although it varies slightly with different sensor/film sizes, apertures, and focal lengths, in general the depth of field (DoF) of acceptable focus at the hyperfocal distance for a given lens at a given aperture will start at around one half the distance from the focal plane to the hyperfocal distance and reach to infinity. Since the hyperfocal distance is defined by the acceptable circle of confusion (CoC), the hyperfocal distance using the same camera, lens at a specific focal length, and aperture will vary for different display sizes of the resulting image.

Be aware that *acceptable focus* can be a tough thing to nail down. It is dependent on variables such as subject matter and the display size of the resulting image. When photographing a landscape with trees in the background setting focus to the hyperfocal distance will probably render the trees acceptably sharp. Using the same technique with a night sky full of stars as the background probably won't result in stars that are satisfactorily sharp.

Answer (score 1):

The DOF ranges from half the hyperfocal distance to infinity.

When a camera is focused on the [hyperfocal distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfocal_distance), all objects from half that distance to infinity is in acceptable focus.