# Why can't I get a decent white background with product photography?

Tags: exposure, product-photography, background, color-white

I'm a new photographer, and I'm trying to take photos of a product with a pure white background (#ffffff). I'm using a light box (something like [this one](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/Professional-Portable-Mini-Photo-Studio-Photography-Light-Box-Photo-Box-MK50-For-Network-EBAY-seller/438341420.html)), so my lighting should be solid.

But I can't seem to find the right settings for a good photo. I've taken lots of photos (100+), with a lot of different settings and basically my photos are either overexposed, or the background is not white. Here are some examples:

**1.**

[image: product great, background too gray]

The product is great on this photo. Only the background is WAY to grey.

f/8 -- 1/2000 sec -- ISO-6400

---

**2.**

[image: background white, product overexposed]

The background is pure white. But the product is overexposed.

f/8 -- 1/320 -- ISO-6400

---

**3.**

[image: too gray and overexposed product]
Too grey and the product is overexposed

f/22 -- 1/200 -- ISO/128000

---

Based on feedback, I have adjusted the exposure parameters and gotten somewhat [better results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaLLF.jpg), but that that alone doesn't solve the fundamental problem. What else do I need to do to get a pure white background without overexposing the subject?

Comment: TL;DR : An all around, all white background isn't just a background. It is a powerful reflector.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many improvements that could be made here. Firstly, you need to use a much longer exposure, and a lower ISO setting. Get a tripod, even a cheap one, and use mirror lockup. Could do with stopping down a bit further for depth of field.

### Post processing

You might be able to get away with your current shots, with some post processing. Here I've taken the second shot and used levels to darken the product whilst leaving the background pure white:

[image]

### Lighting

The proper solution is to look at your lighting. The reason that you cant get the right balance no matter what settings you use is that both the product and background are being lit by the same source, so you can only alter the brightness of both, not each one individually.

Usually you'd have one light for your subject and one for the background. This gives you the correct amount of control for optimum results. However that is only if you have a large curved white background. Compact light tents such as the one you're using wont allow you to light your subject individually.

One solution is to **black out any parts of the light tent not visible in the shot**. That way the amount of light hitting your subject will be decreased, making it darker, without affecting the brightness of the background (since you wont touch any parts that are in shot). Get some thick black card, cut it to size and tape it inside the light tent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt. I can get decent photos with some photoshopping, but it's a lot of work and I plan on making a lot of photos. So thats why I want to get it right "at the source".

I think I understand a little bit better why the light tent is bad. The trick with blacking out sounds good, i'll try that!

Comment: If you standardize your settings when you shoot you can batch apply the same actions to all of the photos in many RAW convertors very easily.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as my solution, thank you. I've learnt that while my settings aren't perfect, it's mostly a problem with lightning that I'm dealing with (as you and others have explained).


I don't have a result yet that I'm satisfied with, but I think I do know how to get it now. I'll start a new topic if I don't ;).

Thanks to everybody for the great help, I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 17):

The white background effect is usually done by lighting the background and the subject separately, you can't do this with such a small box.

There are no camera settings that will help you because your problem is that the difference in brightness between the background and subject is too small - and everything that makes the picture darker or brighter affects both.

What you can do with such a box is to select the settings that correctly expose the subject and then use the levels or curves tool of your favorite photo editor to make the background pure white - that will only work if the subject is darker than the background, it will not work if the subject is white or brightly colored.

A simple way to achieve white background is to place the subject on a transparent material (and piece of glass or clear plastic will do) and point a flash at the wall  behind the subject, the distance between the subject and wall is what lets you blast light into the background without it over exposing the subject.

I blogged about it a while ago [here](http://www.usefulphototips.com/2011/12/20/making-the-background-white/), this doesn't have to be expensive - for the pictures in the blog post I've used the clear plastic from an IKEA picture frame and a $40 flash in a small room that doesn't even have white walls.

Comment: Darn. I was told this box was perfect for things like this. I'll look into your method, the examples you've shown are perfect.

Comment: +1 this is really the correct answer, the background needs more light

Answer (score 10):

You have several opportunities to improve your results!

- The first thing I would do is increase the light enough to get the ISO down to native sensitivity for your camera. Probably ISO 100 or 200.
- You can get the same depth of field (DoF) by increasing the focal length and the focus distance by the same proportion. This will improve the perspective and your box won't look warped. By centering your focus on the nearer part of the box you can utilize the property of DoF that the portion of the DoF behind the center of focus will be more than the portion on front of the center of focus. In your first example I would aim for the space between the red and black rings. The eye expects the nearer part of an object to be the most in focus. It appears you centered focus on the left part of the box that is further away than the rest of the visible parts of the box.
- The next thing I would do is shoot manually and vary the shutter speed (Tv) until the white background is on the verge of blowing out. Some people refer to this as exposing to the right (ETTR). Since your meter thinks everything is 18% grey, it will be screaming that you are overexposing by 2-3 stops. Your tripod will allow you to use slower shutter speeds without inducing motion blur.
- Since you are saving your pictures as RAW files (aren't you?), when you open them in an image editor you can raise the level of the highlights and then the overall exposure until the background does blow out. Then adjust your shadows. If the colors don't look right set your white balance before you blow out the background. Most image editors will let you tell it that the background is white or you can adjust the color temperature until the background is white. Increasing the contrast setting will also increase the difference between the brightest and darkest parts of the scene.

Here's my stab at editing the second shot you posted. In addition to noise reduction I desaturated the color a little to help reduce the noise. This was with a noisy JPEG. Much more can be done with a RAW file.

[image: edited DSC01292]

And the 5th shot, which was much less noisy and exposed more to the right. Again, A RAW file would allow even better results.

[image: edited image #5]

Comment: If you want to have the same effect as a arrow aperture you should not have a long focal length. A long focal length will decrease DoF and a narrow aperture will increase DoF.

Comment: What you say is true at the same focus distance. A longer shooting distance will increase the focus distance which will increase the DoF.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I have added some more photos with a lower ISO, which is indeed better. If I understand correctly, I should find a setting where the photo is overexposed (like DSC01325?) and then play around with shutter speed some more?

Comment: @DNN the problem is not your camera settings, a faster or slower shutter will brighten/darken both the subject and the background, it wont differentially adjust subject background brightness, which is what you need. You need to look at post-processing or changing the lighting to do this.

Comment: Take a series of test shots and use the image histogram to set the shutter speed long enough that you are just short of clipping highlights. For more on how to use the histogram to expose to the right see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETTR. You'll still need to separate the brightness of the background and the brightness of the product in post production using the light curve controls.

Comment: @MattGrum: If he will ETTR he can reduce the noise. I've also found it looks more natural to my eye to boost overall exposure and then to darken the mid-tones and shadows than to boost the highlights as far as the slider will go.

Comment: @MichaelClark: your explanations about ETTR are very good and indeed correct here. However with the depth of field you are quite wrong: the the focal length and the distance do have *no effect* on the DoF if the pixel-size of the object is kept the same. The only thing that changes is the perspective (with the distance). You are quite right in pointing this out: a longer distance can improve the perspective of a box. However, it is a well known fact among photographers that it is impossible to get a box in a full-size photograph completely in-focus. No DoF trick will be able to help you.

Comment: @BogdanWilli You may have misread. If you read the answer carefully you will see this is what I am saying: By changing focal length and subject distance by the same proportion the DoF will remain the same. But by focusing on the nearer (instead of more distant) parts of the product you will give the viewer's eye what it expects to see. Depth of field is an illusion, albeit a convincing one at times. There is only one distance that is most in focus. By presenting the nearer parts of the subject most in focus the viewer's brain will be more likely to *perceive* the entire object as in focus.

Comment: It is also true that the further the subject distance is, the more the DoF behind the point of focus is increased in proportion to the DoF in front of the point of focus. For an object focused closely the DoF can approach 1:1. By the time you focus at or beyond the hyper-focal distance the ratio of front to back is 1:∞.

Comment: You're correct, I've misread your post. English is not my mother-tongue; I don't get your last comment completely. By the time we have a ratio of 1:∞ we're not talking of a complete image-filling photo of a box, do we?

Comment: No, it just means that everything behind the point of focus is within the depth of field for a particular circle of confusion and will appear to the viewer to be in focus. That means to infinity behind the lens. Since the area in front of the lens is still limited (at a maximum of the subject to camera distance) then the ratio of the DoF in front of the point of focus to the DoF behind the point of focus is 1:∞. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-is-hyperfocal-distance

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to be aware of here is the post processing our brains do; brightness values are  also adjusted by the brain. We don't tend to notice this, but without this effect we would have difficulties recognising object due to changes in the lighting conditions. So, it's actually quite a big effect. Even though an object in a shadow looks darker, it actually would look a lot darker than it actually does without the brain modifying the brightness in its post processing.

In a picture you may see strange things due to this effect if the brain will tend to make wrong assumptions about the lighting conditions when looking at the picture. Take e.g. the following picture:

[image]

The top square looks a lot darker than the bottom square, however, they have exactly the same brighness. The reason why we percieve a brighness difference is because the brain thinks that the bottom square is in a shadow while the top square is exposed to bright light. This prompts the brain to increase the brightness of the lower square relative to the top square.

If you put your finger between the two squares so that you don't see the boundary between them, then the effect goes away, the two squares will look as bright.

Now, in the posted pictures this effect will also play a role when comparing the different pictures with each other. Not only will the camera expose differently when the brightness of the object relative to the background is changed, your brain will then also change its own post processing which will then change the effect we actually observe.

Comment: Is there a source for this picture? At the moment, I'm trying to track down its author.

Answer (score 3):

Use some translucent perspex, it's flexible so it will bend for the curve, and place a light or lights behind it for your background, this way you can balance the lighting. Also use black cards around the edges of the box so you don't get those nasty reflections, and then cut out the card or paper that's in the shot with Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

Select the object (product) so you can adjust background and object separately. 
It may be possible to do everything with lights, but the simple solution is to select the product   using Photoshop (or whatever tool you use). Then the background can go to all white and the product can be adjusted properly. 
This will eliminate or at least lessen the flaring on the right side. Of course the lighter the background compared with the product the easier it will be to get good results, so all the photography advice helps...

Comment: This is particularly easy when the subject has hard edges, like the example ink cartridge box. When there are softer edges, or fine details, it's really hard to get the selection perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try overexposing the white background and see if that helps. 
You can achieve this by adding some gap between the product and the background and firing a flash from that gap onto the background. Try to get 3-4 stops of extra exposure on the background so that when you expose properly for the subject, the background will appear completely white.

Answer (score -1):

You may find this could be a metering issue or colour temperature issue.

Use the correct WB setting on your camera for the type of light in your lightbox.  Then also use spot metering on the product itself, ensuring your aperture is set small enough for complete front-to-back sharpness.

As well as the constant lighting within the box itself I would perhaps recommend that you use a flash to light the product too.  This will balance the exposure between the product and the background...

Comment: I'll try using a flash again. The last time I did, it ended up highlighting the product badly and not evenly. And I figured the lighting was good because of the box. 

Thanks for the tip on spot metering. First time I've heard about it, i'll look into it!

Comment: -1 I don't see how firing a flash into the box is going to fix the problem of the product being **too bright compared to the background**. Nor do I see how this can be a problem with white balance.

Comment: Just a guess based off the last portrait session I did where I lit the background and the subject separately.  Thought maybe the same would apply to this as I figured maybe the dynamic range was too great for the camera to handle.  By illuminating the subject as well as the background you even it out.

Comment: But he wants to increase contrast, not decrease it.