# What kind of lens is required for macro jewelry photography to get everything in focus?

Tags: macro, product-photography, lens-recommendation, jewelry

I'd like to know if anybody has any tips regarding the lens I should use to get this kind of image. I'm planning on shooting product pictures of jewelry. I know that usually the go-to lens is macro, but I don't like the fact that I can only focus on the front or the back of the ring; I would like all the piece in focus, just like this image.

I'll number the different options I *think* were used, but please let me know which you think is the most likely to be used:

1. macro with focus stacking
2. tele-macro
3. another lens? (it doesn't look like a 55/55 as the piece is really focused and sharp, or at least that's my assumption with what I know of photography, please note I'm a jeweler with a personal project trying to take my own pictures as I don't have the budget yet to give the job to someone that really know.)

[image]
([source](https://tomwood.centracdn.net/client/dynamic/images/2783_2ea6c55360-compassblack-sc_full.jpg))

Comment: Have you searched the site for jewelry photography specifically and product photography in general?  I have seen other questions that discuss this.  Specifically, does https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89121/what-kind-of-lens-do-i-need-to-take-a-photo-of-jewelry-like-this?rq=1 answer your question?  I found it in the related list to the right.

Comment: This does not look like a picture that would necessarily require some special kind of lens. Although a macro lens would be preferrable, but even without that , you can get very good results if you just use the proper techniques for lighting and using the appropriate aperture and focus.

Comment: A *tilt-shift* lens might be helpful. If you have a mirrorless camera (or a digital back), you could also have a look at recent view camera systems such as the [Cambo Actus series](https://www.cambo.com/en/actus-series/).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is you want entire object on focus. So you can do few things:

1. Close the aperture. But do not go behind f9,f10 otherwise diffraction will make your image softer
2. Use technique named [focus stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stacking). This need additional equipment to move your camera (or focus) on small steps.
3. Use different lens. [Tilt-shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt%E2%80%93shift_photography#Tilt) lens can give you entire object on focus. But they are expensive :(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127716/discussion-on-answer-by-romeo-ninov-what-kind-of-lens-is-required-for-macro-jewe).