# How can I photograph a toy against a white background, leaving the toy in shadow?

Tags: lighting, product-photography

[image: Image belongs to Kuroneko_oxyz]

I saw this image of a toy online and have been wondering how I can photograph an object so it is in shadow but against a pure white background like this. According to the exif, the photo was shot with f/20, ISO 100 and exposure time is 30 sec. How was the lighting set up in this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I get a decent white background with product photgraphy?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38343/why-cant-i-get-a-decent-white-background-with-product-photgraphy)

Comment: I want to know how can you cast shadow on an object in a white background or any terms that related to it not how to get a decent white background

Comment: Please ask specifically what you're looking for in the question title. That's what people who can answer the question will see first.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast a shadow"?

Comment: Do you mean "white background where the object is not well lit from the front"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i mean, i want that shadow on the object like in the picture, i tried many times but all the results were either overexposed or too bright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably on a still life table and backlit. Looks like either a LED or fluorescent softbox as the main source.

Comment: Actually, I'd guess natural light--window light through some diffuser--curtain, paper, something.